# When does a JavaScript redirect actually take effect?

Tags: javascript, redirect

If I use a server-side redirect in ASP.NET code, I know that it will raise a ThreadAbortException and so all processing on the page will immediately stop and the redirect will happen straight away (after "finally" clauses).

However, Say I do a redirect inside a JavaScript block (by setting location.href or using location.replace), when does this redirect actually take effect?

Reloading the page would obviously unload the current script block but based on a quick test, an alert statement after the redirect still works. Does the redirect take place only once processing of the current event has completed? More importantly is this behaviour standardized, or just a de-facto convention?

Comment: It's possible they're simply delaying via https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload behind the scenes, but it's hard to say without seeing a sample.

Comment: From my experience, the exact timing of a JS redirect is not standard among browsers.  Sometimes, it kicks off immediately and sometimes some other Javascript after it executes before the redirect starts.

Answer (score 1):

OK I've done some more of my own tests. Jerebear is right as far as he goes in that if you have a redirect that happens directly inside a script tag (i.e. the redirect is executed when the script tag is loaded) then this stops loading any further script tags on the same page. so if you have something like:

```
<script> a(); redirect(); b(); </script>
<script> c(); </script>
```

then a and b would be executed but not c, because the second script would never be loaded.

However, this is only part of the story. I was really thinking about what happens when you redirect as a result of an event (click, timer etc). The answer to this is that doing a redirect does not stop events being processed on the page at all. This means all events continue to work normally until the new page starts to load.

So the general answer is that the redirect doesn't really take effect until the new page is received from the server, although it does have the side effect of not loading any more script tags (and possibly not loading other resources) on the current page.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect happens at the end of processing everything inside the set of 'script' tags.  This way the DOM can put everything within that script tag into memory when processing the individual operations.

If you had processing in a secondary set of script tags, those instructions would be ignored.

Comment: so let's say the redirect was in response to an event (for instance a button click), would all handlers on that event be invoked before the redirect happens, or does that in any way depend on which script block the handlers are defined in ?

Comment: Are these actions being attached to the button via jQuery or something similar?

Comment: "The redirect happens at the end of processing everything inside the set of 'script' tags" --- that's implementation details. No standard (?) prevents a particular client to redirect immediately as soon as some redirect instruction is evaluated.